# magnetic field sensor in gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all, how can i modell a magnetic field sensor in Gazebo??
Can anybody please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12543/magnetic-field-sensor-in-gazebo?/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-01-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the gazebo_ros_p3d plugin to retrieve ground truth pose data. Depending on your needs you might want to increase gaussian noise, or write your own plugin based on gazebo_ros_p3d (if you need a more sophisticated error model than gaussian noise).

```
  <controller:gazebo_ros_p3d name="quadro_groundtruth_sim" plugin="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
    <bodyName>quadrotor_base</bodyName>
    <topicName>ground_truth_pose</topicName>
    <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
    <frameName>map</frameName>
    <interface:position name="my_box_p3d_position_iface" />
  </controller:gazebo_ros_p3d>
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-06**:
@mukmuk: Yes, you can ;)

**Comment by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on 2012-01-06**:
@stefan , thanks. ps:hey kann ich dich über email anschreiben?thema:quadrokopter

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-06**:
@mukmuk. Actually, for the purpose of simulating magnetic field sensors, both provide viable attitude data (the gazebo_ros_p3d plugin however outputs ground truth translation too). I'm not aware of  a plugin providing data in tesla, you could generate something like that from attitude data though.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-01-06**:
@Arkapravo Have a look at http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo_plugins . All that will probably change significantly with the new Fuerte ROS version though, as gazebo and it's plugin architecture will receive a major upgrade.

**Comment by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on 2012-01-06**:
hi,where is the difference between this plugin and gazebo_ros_imu plugin???And where do i get the magnetic field data in tesla unit??

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-01-06**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher : Is there any list for such gazebo plugins ? Any website/ link you may refer me to ?